# Replace spaces and / between two brackets in bash

Tags: bash, sed, replace, brackets

I have this (text) file:

```
[check consumer TAIL_SCE_O_P]
[CheckCo on IEB02]
[CheckSubscribers consumers for ne/os/jms/queue/FT_PN_IN]
[CheckSubscribers consumers for ne/os/jms/queue/SO_IN]
Please do not change/me/thank/you
another bracketless text
```

I would like replace spaces ( ) and / to an - between brackets

Example output:

```
[check-consumer-TAIL_SCE_O_P]
[CheckCo-on-IEB02]
[CheckSubscribers-consumers-for-ne-os-jms-queue-FT_PN_IN]
[CheckSubscribers-consumers-for-ne-os-jms-queue-SO_IN]
Please do not change/me/thank/you
another bracketless text
```

I have tried this:

```
cat output.txt |grep "\[" | sed 's/\ /-/g'
```

But it is changed a lot of tings.

Comment: Do you want to replace spaces and `/` with `-` in all lines beginning with `[`?

Comment: Yes. This will be okay for me.

Comment: @ZoliloZ : What is the desired behaviour with a pair of brackets, where opening and closing brackets are in different lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input data:

```
$ cat output.txt
[check consumer TAIL_SCE_O_P]
[CheckCo on IEB02]
[CheckSubscribers consumers for ne/os/jms/queue/FT_PN_IN]
[CheckSubscribers consumers for ne/os/jms/queue/SO_IN]
Please do not change/me/thank/you
another bracketless text
```

One `sed` solution:

```
$ sed '/\[/,/]/{s/[ /]/-/g}' output.txt
```

Where:

- `/\[/` + `,` + `/]/` - start of range is a left bracket; end of range is a right bracket
- `{s/[ /]/-/g}` - within the range replace all spaces ( ) and forward slashes (`/`) with a hyphen (`-`)

The above generates:

```
[check-consumer-TAIL_SCE_O_P]
[CheckCo-on-IEB02]
[CheckSubscribers-consumers-for-ne-os-jms-queue-FT_PN_IN]
[CheckSubscribers-consumers-for-ne-os-jms-queue-SO_IN]
Please do not change/me/thank/you
another bracketless text
```

Comment: `/\[/,/]/` that would also replace lines with one brace. It starts _at line_ with left bracket and end _at another line_ with right bracket. You want `/\[.*]/` - match both brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
sed '/^\[.*]$/s/[[:space:]\/]/-/g' file
# => 
# [check-consumer-TAIL_SCE_O_P]
# [CheckCo-on-IEB02]
# [CheckSubscribers-consumers-for-ne-os-jms-queue-FT_PN_IN]
# [CheckSubscribers-consumers-for-ne-os-jms-queue-SO_IN]
# Please do not change/me/thank/you
# another bracketless text
```

It means:

- `/^\[.*]$/`  - find a line that starts with `[` and ends with `]`
- `s/[[:space:]\/]/-/g` - and on that line, replace a whitespace or `/` with a `-`.

See [an online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/xXVfu2).